# Perl: transform string into array and print line number

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I have the following string `Today, the sky is blue.` and I would like to do two things with it.

First, I'd like to turn it into the following array (or hash, not sure which one is the right one).

```
Today
,

the

sky 

is 

blue
.
```

I can do it using this grep `grep -Eo '\w+|[^\w ]' input.txt` , but could somebody please tell me how to do this using perl (in order to run this as part of a script for example).

Second thing, I'd like to add the line number to each line of my array (I know it's there somewhere but I want to actually see it), resulting in the following final output:

```
Today     1
,         2
          3
the       4
          5
sky       6
          7
is        8
          9
blue      10
.         11
```

Could somebody help me use that grep function in a perlish context and print the corresponding line number ? Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
my $text = "Today, the sky is blue.";
my @list = split/(\W)/, $text;
my $i = 1;
for (@list) {
    say $_,"\t",$i++ if $_ ne '';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Today   1
,   2
    3
the 4
    5
sky 6
    7
is  8
    9
blue    10
.   11
```

Comment: The for loop looks a little messy. I prefer `for (@list) { say $_ . "\t" . $i++ if $_ }`

Comment: @Joshua: Yes, you're right. In first version I printed `$_` instead of `$i` but it begun by 0. I've added `$i` after but not change the loop :(

Comment: You can still declare as `0` if you instead pre-increment in the print `++i`

Answer (score 1):

For matching regexes in Perl you have the matching operator, you will find many examples and explanations about it in the [PerlRegex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

So you would reuse whatever regexes like this; here I am putting the results into an array, that contains the matches. Any postprocessing should be applied to this array. Here I am just outputting it.

One more detail concerning your regex - if I do this, using the regex you gave

```
echo "Today, the sky is blue." | grep -Eo '\w+|[^\w ]'
```

The output is:

```
Today
,
the
sky
is
blue
.
```

This is because your negated character class `[^\w ]` not only excludes alphanumeric characters but spaces too.

However, according to your output you probably have `[^\w]` here, so the space, which is not part of `\w` is treated as match. So I am using this regex here too. By the way: I wonder, if you really want every non-word *character* to be a match of its own.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>)
{
    my (@matches) = $_ =~ m/(\w+|[^\w])/g;

    print join("\n", @matches);
}

__DATA__
Today, the sky is blue.
```

Comment: This doesn't give the wanted result.

Comment: What do you mean? I did not number the output and there is a trailing newline, ok.

Comment: Ok, now I see it - the spaces are missing.